# Trying to migrate model from Tensorflow 1.15.3 to Keras and Tensorflow 2.3.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, migration, lstm

I have a model that I'm really not understanding how to convert to a Keras model, if someone can take a look and help me get started, i'd really appreciate it! I'm trying to find a way to use the "self." values within a keras LSTM model. I can't really figure out a way thru looking at other forums to do this and the tensorflow migration tutorial isn't really helpful for my particular issue.

If someone also has a suggestion for a similar keras model that would also be very helpful!

Right now it is using compat.v1 to allow me to run in Tensorflow 2.0.

Code:

```python
class Model:
    def __init__(
        self,
        learning_rate,
        num_layers,
        size,
        size_layer,
        output_size,
        forget_bias = 0.1,
    ):
        def lstm_cell(size_layer):
            return tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(size_layer, state_is_tuple = False)

        rnn_cells = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.MultiRNNCell(
            [lstm_cell(size_layer) for _ in range(num_layers)],
            state_is_tuple = False,
        )
        self.X = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, None, size))
        self.Y = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(tf.float32, (None, output_size))
        drop = tf.nn.RNNCellDropoutWrapper(
            rnn_cells, output_keep_prob = forget_bias
        )
        self.hidden_layer = tf.compat.v1.placeholder(
            tf.float32, (None, num_layers * 2 * size_layer)
        )
        self.outputs, self.last_state = tf.compat.v1.nn.dynamic_rnn(
            drop, self.X, initial_state = self.hidden_layer, dtype = tf.float32
        )
        self.logits = tf.compat.v1.layers.dense(self.outputs[-1], output_size)
        self.cost = tf.reduce_mean(input_tensor=tf.square(self.Y - self.logits))
        self.optimizer = tf.compat.v1.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(
            self.cost
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that tf functions like tf.reduce_mean, K.mean, tf.square, tf.exp etc. implemented in a loss funtion cause the error:

> Inputs to eager execution function cannot be Keras symbolic tensors

This was the main migrating problem I had between tensorflow versions you mentioned in the title.